# How can multiple (4) worker process setup done in nginx windows

Tags: nginx

Can you please let me know how nginx config can be updated to configure 4 worker process and use them efficiently through nginx (installed on Windows platform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you cannot. From [the nginx website](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html), under "known issues":

- Although several workers can be started, **only one of them actually does any work**.

To make this perfectly clear: this is an issue with **Windows** nginx, not a general nginx issue!

Comment: How about nginx on WSL?